# Stopping a Timer Task from within a Runnable thread when shutdown

Tags: java, runnable, executorservice, timertask

I have a TimerTask that gets started as the first thing in my run() method of my Runnable class.  I want to make sure that it gets stopped when the runnable is shutdown.

The runnable is started via an ExecutorService. I don't see a way to get a hook back to the runnable from the ExecutorService when shutdown() is called.

How can I make sure that the TimerTask is stopped?

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you mean a `Timer`? A `TimerTask` is just another `Runnable`. Which begs the question ... why are you starting another thread inside a Runnable that's in a threadpool?

Answer (score 0):

The method call `TimerTask.cancel()` should do the desired.

Your `Runnable.run` method could be designed like this:

```
public void run() {
    pingTask = new PingTimerTask(...);
    try {
        ...
    } finally {
        /* this code even gets executed when an exception
         * (for example an *InterruptedException*) was thrown:
         */
        pingTask.cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: I use TimerTask.cancel() to stop it in a normal running situation. I'm more concerned that the server was stopped and the runnable gets interrupted and making sure I stop the TimerTask as well.

Comment: Here's some more details. Inside my run() method of my Runnable (started by calling executorService.execute(new Parser(file));)
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    pingTask = new PingTimerTask(getHandlerService().findGptsRootUrl(), getParserFile().getInputFileStatusId());
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(pingTask, TIMER_DELAY, TIMER_DELAY);

at the end I call pingTask.cancel() to stop the timer from running again.

Comment: I found that the key was to call cancel() on the Timer object itself and not on the scheduled TimerTask object.  I no longer see any references to the Timer thread still running.

Answer (score 0):

use ExecuterService.submit() to get back Future object once the task is completed.

[ExecutorService.Submit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Comment: Brian, I have a process that needs to ping back another service every x minutes while it's running (basically telling the service it's still working). I thought a TimerTask that started at the beginning and stopped at the end would be the best route for handling that.  
I'll look at the submit method using a future.